# Condition for two filters to have a common limit

Tags: general-topology

I would like to prove that, given a filter $\mathcal{F}$, the collection of all limit points of $\mathcal{F}$ is closed. If I call such a set as $C$, then I need to show $\overline{C} \subseteq C$. If $x \in \overline{C}$, then, for every neighborhood $N_x$ containing $x$, $N_x \cap C \neq \emptyset$, which implies that there exists a filter $\mathcal{F}_2$ such that $\mathcal{F}_2 \to x$. I am sure I can use this result to show that $\mathcal{F} \to x$ as well, but struggling to come up with an idea. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by limit point? A point to which the filter converges or to which it accumulates? Often the naming is confusing

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta It seems to me that the terminology is actually pretty consistent:  "accumulation point of a filter" and "cluster point of a filter" mean the same thing ($x$ is in the closure of every set in $F$, equivalently every neighborhood of $x$ intersects every set in $F$ nontrivially), while "limit of a filter", "limit point of a filter", and "$F$ converges to $x$" mean the same stronger thing (every neighborhood of $x$ is in $F$). Then $x$ is an accumulation point of $F$ if and only if there is a filter $F'$ such that $F\subseteq F'$ and $x$ is a limit point of $F'$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman completely agree with you, just asking since when I first tackle the subject I was pretty confused between the two, maybe for the terminology on sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is in the closure of $C$. We need to show that every open neighborhood of $x$ is in $\mathcal{F}$. So let $x\in U$ be open. Then there is some $y\in U\cap C$, so $U$ is also an open neighborhood of $y$. Since $y\in C$, $U\in \mathcal{F}$, and we're done.

Comment: You showed the limits of F, the points x for which F -> x, is closed.  Is the limit of a filter the same or different than a limit point?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I understand a "limit point of $F$" to be a point which is a limit of $F$, i.e. a point $x$ such that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, $U\in F$. Do you think this is not what the OP intended?

Comment: The limit of a function is never referred to as a limit point.  One knows not what OP intended with his misnomer.

Comment: @WilliamElliot It's common to say "limit point of" instead of "limit of" in contexts where the limit may not be unique. So for example I would refer to "a limit point of a sequence", especially when the sequence does not converge. Filters are often used as replacements for sequences in more general spaces, so I'm not surprised to see the same terminology used in this context.

Comment: @WilliamElliot ... and it's not without precedent: see Definition 1 on p. 68 of Bourbaki's General Topology! (I'm looking at the English translation) Or for a less authoritative but more accessible source: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Limit_Point#Limit_Point_of_Filter. Googling "limit point of a filter" provides many more examples.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, Alex's definition of limit point is what I intended.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ is not a limit (point) of the filter $\mathcal{F}$, this means there is an open neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ that is not a member of $\mathcal{F}$.

Note that this same $O$ witnesses for any $p \in O$ that $p$ is not a limit point of $\mathcal{F}$ either. So this $O$ misses the set of limits of $\mathcal{F}$ entirely. This shows that the set of limits of $\mathcal{F}$ is closed.

If the OP meant by limit point “accumulation point” of $\mathcal{F}$, then this set can be seen as $$\bigcap \{\overline{F}: F \in \mathcal{F}\}$$ which is clearly closed as an intersection of closed sets.

Comment: Thank you so much for the additional insight, greatly appreciated.